# Platform Independent Text Hashing with Python

Tags: python, hash

Is there any function in Python's stdlib or extra package for generating a consistent hash from text independent of the platform and architexture?

I had been using this code:

```py
import hashlib

def get_text_hash(text):
    h = hashlib.sha512()
    if not isinstance(text, unicode):
        text = unicode(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
    h.update(text.encode('utf-8', 'replace'))
    return h.hexdigest()
```

But I found that it returns completely different hashes for the same text on Fedora 16 vs Ubuntu 12.

EDIT: Here is code to reproduce the problem:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import hashlib

def get_file_hash(fin):
    """
    Iteratively builds a file hash without loading the entire file into memory.
    """
    if isinstance(fin, basestring):
        fin = open(fin)
    h = hashlib.sha512()
    for text in fin.readlines():
        if not isinstance(text, unicode):
            text = unicode(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
        h.update(text.encode('utf-8', 'replace'))
    return h.hexdigest()

def get_text_hash(text):
    """
    Returns the hash of the given text.
    """
    h = hashlib.sha512()
    if not isinstance(text, unicode):
        text = unicode(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
    h.update(text.encode('utf-8', 'replace'))
    return h.hexdigest()

image_content = '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x009\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00t\xf8xr\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00\xae\xce\x1c\xe9\x00\x00\x00\x06bKGD\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\xa0\xbd\xa7\x93\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x1e\xc2\x00\x00\x1e\xc2\x01n\xd0u>\x00\x00\x00\x07tIME\x07\xdc\x08\x15\r0\x02\xc7\x0f^\x14\x00\x00\x0eNIDATh\xde\xd5\x9aytTU\x9e\xc7?\xf7\xbdWkRd\x0f\x01\x12\x02!\xc8\x120,\r6\xb2#\x10\xa2(\xeeK\xdb:n\xd3\xca\xd0\xb46\x8b\xf6\xc09=\xd3v\xdb\xa7\x91\xb8\xb5L\xab\xe3\xb8\xb5\x8c\xbd\x88\x83\xda-\x84\xc4\xb84\x13\x10F\x01\r\xb2%\x01C \tY\x8a$UIj{\xef\xce\x1f\xaf\xaa\x92\x90\x80@\xc0\xa6\xef9uRU\xa9\xba\xf7\xf7\xbd\xdf\xdf\xfe+\xb8Xk\xc1\x8aD\xe6/K\x03 \x7f%\x17{)\x17kcUU/s%\xa6\xbce[\xf8h6\x9b\xd7B\xfe\x8a\x7fL \xe9)I\t\xd3\'O\x9c-\xe2\x07\xfc\x89\x9c\xd9N6\x17\\Tf.\x1a\x90\xe1\x19\xa9\xa3\xe6\x8d\x19\x84\x96>f\x02#\xe6l\x02`\xf3ZX\xb0\xe2\x1f\x08\xc8\x84\xfb\xfb\xa5\xc6\xc7.\x9c;&\x1d\xabE\x95d\x8c\x9f\xc1\r\xbfx\x95\xf4\\\x85\xc2\x82\x8b\x02F\xb9\x80\xc6M\xcc\xf5\xab\x01p\x0eI\x9f1kl\xd6\xeca)\xfd\xb0)\x8a@\xb3\n\x06\xe4\xdc\xcb\x15\xb7\xad\xe1\xca\x1f:L0\xcb\xb9\xf4V\xd7\x1b\xce\xbec\xfe\xea7\x8bO\x18R\xca\x0f\xcb\xdd\x86kU\x89d\xd9\x16\x83\xe5E\x92%\xefHnyr#\xdf\xbb%\xbd\xf3\xbb\x17\x06\x90\xda\xe7\x1d\xf2W@a\x81\xf9|\xe6OV\xad\x7fz\xc9\xb3?\xbe\xe6\xfbI\xfb\x1b\xda\xe5\xafK\xbe\x11_\xd7y\x91\x08\x01H4\x9b\xc0\x95<\x12W\xf2\x1d$\x0fm\xe6\xc8\xce\xddTl7/\xa2b[\x9f\xc4\x10\xe7\xcd@D\xf8\xa1\xb7*\xd6\x9c\xac\x01\xb9C\x07\xbc\xf8\xdc\xe2E\x0bs\xb2\xd2)>\xe4f\xcb\xc1&^\xdfy\x8c\xa0n`\xe2\x08/)%B\x08:Z\xe1D\xf9\x0e\x02\xde\xd5H\xb6q\xb2\xdaO\xe9\xef\x8d\xef\x96\x91\xc8\xed\r\xbfcX\xde\xeds\xef\xbf\xe1\xca\xb1\x7f~n\xf1\xf5cGe\xa4\xcaV\x7f\x88=5mB\x02\xfb\xeb\xdb\xf0\xfaC\xdd\x81\x880;\x16\xbb ~`:V\xe7\xdd(\xea-\xc4$\xda\xc9\xc8m\xa1b[C\xf4\xb2\xce\x81%q.*\xe4Tm\xb4\xff\xf5\t`J\xf2e\xf7\xdf\xf0\xf0\xe2k\xa7\xdc>m\xf4\x90\xec\xef\rO\x07\x90\x80\x08\xea\x06\xaf}QGY\x8d\x87\xff\xfa\xec\x18\xbe\xa0\xde\x1dH\'3 \x84\x0c\x8b \xf0{\xc1\xd7Z\x83\xbbz\x03u\x07\xd6\xb2m\xfd1~\xf0[p\x1f\xedd\xbf\xcf@\xf2W\x9a1\x00`\xd2\x8f\xee[ro\xfe\x13\x8f\xdd<+e@\xa2K\xd5T5\n\x02\xe0\xbd\xaf\x1b\xa9h\xea\xe0\xc5\xd2\xa3T4\xb4\x99\xef\x8a3\x1c\x13\x05\x84@J0t\x89\xbb\xba\x9e\xe3e\x8fQ\xb2\xee\r\xf3\xfc\xe5\xb0\xf9\xa9>\x00\xe9\n`\xce\xc3\xc9C3\x07\xbc\xf9\xc6\xb2[\x17L\x1f3T\x86\xd5]tj\x0b|\\\xd9\xcc\xd7\'\xdax\xb7\xac\x8e\x92\xfd\x8d\xa0\x9d\x87w7\x81A[3\xd4\xee[G[\xd3c|\xf8|;\xf9\x8f\xc2\xe6\'\xcf\xc3F\xba\x80p,Z5\xfb\x9f\x17^\xf9\xde\x7f?z\xc7\xe4Q\x83S\x91R\n\x11\x96^\x08AP\x97|v\xb4\x95/k\xbd|x\xa8\x91\xc2\xb2z\xb0\x9c\xa7C\x8c\xb0gs\x803~20\x82\xd4\xecR\x8a\x9f\xf5\x90\xff(T\x94\x9e\x03\x90\xaeL,X\xb1d\xdd\x92\x1b^\\~\xe3\x8cA\t\xb1\x0e\xd9\x95E!\x04\xed\x01\x9d\x8f\x0f7SV\xd7\xc6\xa6\x03\rl\xda\xd7\x00\xea\x05\x88\xb3RJ\xacvp\xb8r\xd0\xacS\x89M\xfa\x94\x8f_p\x9f\xce\t\xa8\xbd\xc6\x85\xcda\xe3\x9a\xb1\xf4\xf1\xa2\xb5K~y\xf3\xb4\xb1\xb16\x8b&\xc3L\x10yT7\xfb\xd8t\xc0MM\xab\x9f\xff\xf9\xea\x04\x1f\x957u\xbf\xd5>\x05\x06a\xda\x8cj\x01g|\x06\xd6\x98\xd98b?\xe0\xd3\x97[X\xb0\x1c*\xb6\x7f\x0b\x90\x08\xda\xbc\xe5K\x8b\n\x96<>o|\xb6\x85\x88\xc9\x86=g\xc8\x80]\xc7\xbd|\\\xd9\x8c\xc7\xa7\xf3\xf2\xf6j>\xafj\x06E\\\x18\x10\xdd]\xb5\x00!q\xc6\xf5\xc7\xea\x1cMB\xfa\x07|\xf4\x1f\xbeS\xc1\xa8=\x02]\xc56\x1c\x8bV\xcd}\xe6\xa1\xeb_\xbcm\xfa\xe51\x11\x00B\x08tCR\xe7\t\xf0Ie3\xbbk\xbcT6\xb5\xf3\xfc\xd6*\xaa\xdd\x1d\x17F\x9d\xce\x04HQA\xb3g#uH\xc9,\xc1\xea\xeaf/j7\xbb(,@,X\x9e\xb4h\xfa\xc4\xf7V\xdf6{\x80\xd3\xa6\xc9\x88Q\xd7\xb4\xf8\xf9\xbfc\x1evV{\xa8hj\xa7p\x7f\x03\x1b\xbf:A{P\x07\xe5"\x82\xe8b5Xl\x02_\xcb4B\xa1=\x14\xae=\xc0\x82\x95Q\r\xd2\xba~\x0e\xc0\xe9\x8a{\xfd\xba9S\x86%\xc4\xd8$ \xaaN\xfa\xf8\xaa\xd6K\xbd7H\xc8\x90\x94\x947Rt\xb0\x89\x96\x8eP\xf4;\xdf\xd1\x12\x08Eb\x8b\x15\xd8b~\xcfU\xff\x92I\xe1\xda\x93\x91t\xa9\xbbB\xcfX|\xfd\xac\xebn\xda\xf8\x83\xe99RS\xa4\xe8\x08\x1a\x84\x0cS\xd8\xc3M\xed\xbc\xf5E\r\r\xde\xc0\x85\xb5\x83s\x89/\x8a\nMU\x12_\xb3\xa0\xa5\xfe\x1d6\xad\xb9\xd94\x89\x95(]\xd2h\x8d\xb4\xe1\x05\xce\x84\x14\xfc\xc1\x90hj\x0bR\xef\r\xf0u\xad\x97u[\xabx\xee\xa3\xc34x\xfeN \xa2\x9eP\x824L\xe3w\xc4/`\xfe#SM\x90\x06\x1a"\xac\xdfW?v\x1f\xfd\xb32>)o\x94\r\x1e\x9f\xf0\xeb\x065->\x1a[\xfcf\xf9\xa5*\x7f?\x10\x91e\x18 u\x90R`\xb1\xc4`s=H\xca\x88mly\xcaL1\x18\xb70\x86\xb1W\xbfM\xf2\xd0|\x84\xd2\xa9\xfa\x82\x0b\x17\x17.\xc4\n\x05\xa0\xe9\x1b\x08\xf9\xcd\xd7A\xdfQ<\x8d\x0b)z\xa6\xcc\xa4\xa3\xff\x8818\xe2\'\xa1\xa8\xa6\xd0\x8a\xe8\x8c\t\x97\n\x08\x80\x90\x0f\x8c`\xe7\xe5*\xea`l\xb1S\x99\xf6O(dM\x82\xf8\x81\x13\xd0\xac\xc9\\\xaaKJ\xf3\xe1o\x03#Z\x16HT\x0b(\xcau8\x13\x1d\nC&\xd9\xd1,Wa\x8b\xe5\xbb\xf6\xa7\xe7d\xe8z\x10\xda\x9b;\xf5]J\x11f\xe5*\xac\x0e\xa7B\xbf\xfe6T\xeb,T\x15$\xe2\x92d\x03\x01\xdeFS\xad"\xaa\x1eaE\xb3X\x91r\xa2\x82\xaa%a\xb1\'\xf5\xa1\x82\xbf\xf8l\xf8\xbd\xe0m \xeaa\xbb\x06I\xd5\x02\xd2\x98\xa1\xa0\x07Ga\x8b\x01y\x89\xa9\x95\x0c\x8b\xa3\x07\xc0]\xd5\x1b\x88p\x11\xa6\x82\xa2\xe6*\x18F&\x16; \xc5%i\x17\xee\xea\xae\x06\xde{\x11\xa6hY\nR&\xa3Z/AOe@s\r\x04\xda\xbf5\x97DQ\x924\x90j\x9fc\x85\x94=\xf6\xeefo\xe7\xb2\x7f\xa4f?Y\r\xbe\x96p9"z\xdf7\x9a\xc3k\x0e\xed\xbc-\xdc\x90(\xaa`p\x82\x9d\x1bF\xa72wD"\xd9\xc9N\x12\x9d\x164E\xe1PC\x1b\x7f\xfd\xba\x9e\re\r|s\xb2\x83\x0e\x9fn\xa6:\xa7o\ru2\xe1>\n\x1d\x9e\xce\xf2 |Qi\t1\xf4\xb3\xdbh\x0f\x049\xd1\xd2N0\xa8\x9b\x81\x1bEj\x08\xbc\xe8!P\xb5\xb3\x07\xa1\x1b$\xbbl,\x9d\x96\xc1\xe2\xa9\x19\xa4\xc4\xf4T\xcd\xc9\x83\xe3\x98<8\x8eU\xf3\x86\xf1\xa7\xdd\xb5\xbc\xbc\xa3\x86\xd2\n\xb7Y\x01\x9d\n&\xf2:\xe8\x83\xe6\xe3\x10h\xeb\x04\xe1\x0f\x92\x96\x1a\xc7\x8f\xe6\x8c\xe5\xa6+\x863b`"\xc7\xdc^6|v\x88\x7f\xdb\xb0\x1d\x7f0\x04\xe0S\x199{(\xae\x94\x1b\xd1\xac\xf2\xac\x1c\xb0\x94\x0cJp\xb0\xf1\x9e\\~8q 1V5\xda\x05\xed\xad\x7f`Q\x15\xc6\r\xea\xc7\xa2\x9cT\xfa\xc7\xd9()w#u#|\x93\x116\x14\xf0yLu\n\xf9\xcd\xd7R\x82?\xc8M\xd3G\xf3\xdaCy\xdc:e\x04\xfd\xe3b\xd0\x14\x85\xc4\x18;S/\x1bHK{\x80\xed\xfb\x8e\x81\xe0\x1b\x05E\xad4\rJ\x9c\x15\x08!\x04\x1f\xdc?\x9e)C\xe2\xbb\xb5rO_r\x9b+)\xc6\xc2\xb2\x99\x99\x1c^5\x9d\t\x83\xe3 \x14n\xf3*\nxN\x98\xc9\xa0\x1e\x0exRb\xb7j\xac{(\x8f?,\xbd\x9a\x9c\xf4\xa4\xe8Y]\xcf\xbcf\xc2\x10\x12R\xe2!\xd0Q\xa9\xa0h&\x90\xf0\x06g4\xc2\x90\xc1\xbf\xe7e\x91;\xd0\x15\xddT\x9c\x83!K)\x19\x9c`\xe7\x8b\x9f~\x9f\x9f\xe7g\x13g\x05\xea\x8f@Km\xd4\xee\xac\x9a\xc2\x15\xc3\x07\xf0\xf9\x13w\xb2d\xfe8,\x9a\xda\xe3\xac\xc8\xdf\xf4\x04\x97L\x8dsA\xc8\xbfK\xa3\xbd\xb9\x03G\xdc\x1e\xa41\xee\xcc\xadMHK\xb0\xb3\xfa\xaa\xacs\x06\xd0\xbd\xc3c\xde\xe6/\xf2\x861g\xb0\x9d\x17\x8a\xfcl\xaf\x80@\xc8`tz\x12\xb7^q\x19\x0f\xce\xbd\xbc\xdb\xcd\x9f\xee,\x87U\xc5*$\xa8\x96\x8f5\xbc\x8d>\xe2\x07}H\xd0?\x0e\x8b\xed\xf4v\x122\xb8}|\x1a\xaa"\xce\xa8N\xe7\x02f\xe6\xa8AL\xcaJ\xe5h\xa3\x07\xdd0\x18\x98\x10KB\xac\xfd[U6\xb2\xdauEH#\xd4\x82\xa1\xeeU\xd8\xfaj\x08\xbfg+\x81\xb63g[\x86d\xea\xd0\x84\xf3f\xa370\x00N\x9b\x85\x91\x83\x12\xc9\xc9H\x8e\x828\xcb3\xe4\t\x8f\x1f\x9f\xaf\xa3\x98\xc6\xea\x0e\xd3\xe76T\x96\x91\x90\xbe\x17)\xc7\x9c6\x80II\xb2\xd3\xd2\xe7.hDH\xdd\x90\x1c\xacu\xf3R\xc9Wl\xd8q\x08\xab\xaa\xf2\x93\x05\xe3\xb9gf\x0e\x89\xb1\xf6\xb3aD\x1c\xabk\xa0\xaa\xee\xe4\xfb\xecx\xc5g\x02\xd9\xfa\xda\x11R\x87\x97\xe0J\x19\x8d\xa2\x89^\x99\x11\x82\x86\xb6`\x9f@D\x04\xab\xa8;\xc9K%e\xfc\xae\xf8K\xda=\x1d\xa0\x99\xed\xb5\xe5/\x17\xb3i\xcf\x11\xd6\xdd;\x87\x91\x03\x13M\xe0B\xf4\x10FJI dp\xa4\xaei\x7fp\xfb\xe7\xa5\x00Jt\x90\xd9P\xf1\x9fx\x1a\xda\xa2>\xbcG\x1a \xf80\xdc\xdb\x95R\x9e\xb7:\xfdj\xe3\x0e\xf2\xd7\xbcK\xc1{;i\xef\x08\x98 "\x91\xddi\xa3d\xcf\x11\xae]\xfb.\xa5\x07\x8f\x9b\xc0Os\x96\xd7\x170\xde(\xdaQD\xf5\xdb\x87\xcdNc\xa4\xd7[\xb5\xbb\x81\x01\xa3\xd2I\xcc\x98\x8c\xa2\xc8h\x05\x16Y\x8a`\xd7\xb1VV\xce\x1e\x82US\xce\xca\x18\xbb~\xa6\xf4`\r\xf9\xbf\xd9\xc8\x86\x9d\x87h\xf2t\x80\x94\xb8\x9c6r\x87\xa4\x90\xd9?\x0e_ \x14\x05\xe6\xf6\xfa\xd8\xf2\xd5Q\xa6\x8d\x18Dz\x92\xab\xdb>\xe1\xe7\xf2\x95\xe2]-\xeb\xd7\xac_L\xfb\xc1F\xf2V\x9c\xc2\xda\xe5\xf3,\x0c\x9bYK\xc6\xe5Ih\xb6\x9e\x92\xea\x06\xf3F&\xf3\xee}\xe3p\xf62\xff8\x15\\ \xa4Ss\xb2\x8d_\xbe\xb3\x9dW\x8b\xf6\x80U\x03!\xc8\xee\x1f\xcf3w\xcfb\xe1\x84\xacn\xdf\x7ff\xd3.\xfe\xf5\x8f\xff\x8b?\xa4\x83n02#\x89w\x1e\xb9\x96\xd1\xe1\x80\x18I\x1b\xf7V70\xf6\xfe\'\xd7P\\\xf03\xf2V\xc2\x96\xb5]{\xbf+\xa0t\xbdA\xe6\xb8]\xf8=w!\x10\x18\xba\xc4\xd0\x05F\x08\xf4\x10\xc8\x10\x87k\xdc\x94\xec?N\xbaK%#\xc9\x85\xd6\xa5y\x1d\x01\xd1\xd0\xda\xce\xd6\x03\xc7y~\xcb\x1e\xee{\xa9\x88\xcf\x0f\x1c\x07\x9b\x05$\xdc~\xe5H6\xfd\xecFl\x16\x957\xff\xb6\x8f?\x94\x1e\xa0\xb8\xac\n\xb7\xd7\xc7=3G\xb3\xb7\xba\x89}\xc7\xdd\xa0\x08\x1a\x1b=\xfc\xad\xbc\x961\xe9Id\xa6\xf4\x03\xe0\xa3\x83\'\xc4\xddk\xff\xf8I\xd3\x9f\x7f~\x17\x00\xc3\xa7@\xc5\xf6S\x18\x89\xccF\x16\xaeZ\x8d\xc3\xf5+4\x9b\x99\xf7D\xab\xb3p7C\xd7M\xb5\x18\x9c\xcc\x98A\x89$\xba\x1ch\x9a\x8a\xdf\x1f\xa4\xb2\xbe\x85\xc3\r\xad\x94\xd7\x9d\xc4\xe3\xf1\x99\xe37! \xa43/w\x08E\xabo\xe6\xad\xd2\x03,_\xff)u\x8d\xad\x9d\x9ak\xd5x\xfb\xe1\x85\xe8Rr\xebs\x1ft\x89_:\xa9\x89\xb1\x8c\xcfL\x95zL\xb2\xd8{\xa0\xfcH\xdd\xde=3\xd8\xba\xeeX\xd71yw a\x9a\x98\xbb\xd4\x89#\xeeu\x9c\xf1\xb7D\x07\x95g0\xe2Nu\x92\x18\x86\xec=\xb35$)qN&g\xf5\xa7\xb0\xac\n]7:\xff\x1f6\xe8\xf4\xc4X\xfc\xbaNC\xab\xafg\x91\xd5/\r\xf4\x90\x87\xda\x03\xd7\xb2\xe97\x9f\x92\xb7\x02\xb6\x14\x9ca\x18\x1a\x19\xbbM\xbd\xd7E\xd2\xc0\xcd8\x13\xa6\x86=\x99\t\xe8l\x83\xa1\x94\x9d\x85\x90\xe8\x92\xe9\x1a\xf2\xf4\xb3\x94\x88\x87\x92\xd2L&#\x13_W\xaa@\xb5z8\xb2\xf3\xa7\x14\x16\xbc\xd2\xdbW{\xee\xb8y-\xe4\xad\x80\xd2\xd7<4\x1e\xcf\xa7\xad\xf9/\xe1\xacT\x84\xd99+\x10\x0e\xab\x85I\xc3\xd3\xb0j*\x04\xf5N\x17\xdb\x15DW\xc1u\x03\x02!\x92\\\x0e\xee\x9c>\n\x0cC\xa2j\x92\xb8\x01\x02\xc3h\xe1\xc8\x8eeQ\x10\xbd\xfc\xee\xab\xf7ah\xe56\xc8[\x0e\x9f\xbc\x10`p\xee\xfb\xe6\xcd\x8a\xe9\xa8\x96\xb3\xa3C\xc2\xfc\xdc!lxd!\xb3G\xa5S\xef\xf5QY{\x12:\xfc\xa6\xc0\xba\x0e!\xddL\xe5\x03A\xd0%\x99\x03\x13y`n.O\xdf5\x93E\x13\x87\xf1\xf4\xa62A|\x9a\xa0\xad\xe9\x10\xf5\xe5w\xb2\xb9`cd\x84@\xe1\xda^\x86\'gZ\x11c\x9a\xbfTA\xb1/\xc2\xee|\x1dG\\?\xa0g\x9c9\x85\x91\xac\xfe\xf1\xbc\xbfb\x119\xe9I\xf8\x02!Z;\x02\xec?\xee\xa6\xba\xa9\x15\xb7\xc7\x87aH\xfa\xc5X\xc9L\x89#;-\x9e\xfeqN\xec\x16\x8d\x17\x8bw\xcbU\x9b\xca\xc5I\xbf\x02\xf5\xe5\xef\xe3mZ\xcc\x96\xa7j\xba\xc9\xd3\xeb\x14\xe8\xdbV\xfe\n\x90\n\x14>\t\xb3\x7f\x9c\x8c3\xf65\x1cqW\xa1Y\x1d\xdd:~\xa7\x023\x0c\x84\x10\xac\xbcv\x12\x0f\xcc\x19K\x8a\xcb\x81USP\x15%j\xdf\xbaa\x10\xd4\r\xdcm~\xde\xff\xe20\xcf\x17\xef\xa5\xd2c\t\xe1on\xa2v\xdf\xe3\x14\xff\xf6w\xe1\xc1,l\xe9\xcb/\x1f\xba\xb1\xd3\x85\xd2\xf9\xcb\xe6a\x8fy\x00\x8bc\x06\x8a\x9a\x86\xaau\x02\xea\xda\x97\x95\x12\x02!\x90\x92!\xe9I\x0cK\x8d\'\xc6n&\x9e\x1d\x81\xa0lm\x0f\x88\x1ao\x90\xea\x9a\x16\xd3\xb8m\xf6]\xb4T\x7f\xc07\xbb\x9f\xe5\xcb\xbf\xb8\xcf\xa4J\xe7\x0f\x04\xe8\xe6\xf2.\x9b\xa90db.\xf6\x98\x19\x08\xe5\x1aTm\x0e\x8aEE\xb3t\x8f;]\xca\x80hW]\xb3\x85\xdf\x0b\x814\xaa\x11\xca\x16\x8c\xc0fj\x0el\xa7\xf4\xf5\xda\x1eg\x9d\xd5\x80\xf1|\xd6\xfceP\xf4\xb4\xf9|\xd6\x83\x02\xab\xd3\x81\xd5\x11\x83\x94\x93\x90\xc6,T\xcb8\x145\x1bEI\x02\xe1D\x08\x15)C\x08\xc5\x83P\xeb\x08u\xec#\x14\xdc\x89\xc5\xbe\x05\xa8\xa2\xb9\xa6\x83O^\n\xf4\xa5D\xf8\x7fM\xdd#\x1d\xf5i\xe0U\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'

fn = 'image.png'
open(fn, 'wb').write(image_content)

print get_text_hash(image_content)
print get_file_hash(fn)
print get_text_hash(open(fn, 'rb').read())
print get_text_hash(open(fn, 'r').read())
```

Here is my output on Ubuntu:

```
[user@ubuntu:~]# python --version
Python 2.7.3
[user@ubuntu:~]# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
[user@ubuntu:~]# python test_hash.py
86f43abba8d46fe17cfb6dd1a986b1d086e81a5ad6e3d5c518dc10e8c7229dc366a4129275a609cda7b87cf0afaf82295421098159327e46b7541e2063341eb2
86f43abba8d46fe17cfb6dd1a986b1d086e81a5ad6e3d5c518dc10e8c7229dc366a4129275a609cda7b87cf0afaf82295421098159327e46b7541e2063341eb2
86f43abba8d46fe17cfb6dd1a986b1d086e81a5ad6e3d5c518dc10e8c7229dc366a4129275a609cda7b87cf0afaf82295421098159327e46b7541e2063341eb2
86f43abba8d46fe17cfb6dd1a986b1d086e81a5ad6e3d5c518dc10e8c7229dc366a4129275a609cda7b87cf0afaf82295421098159327e46b7541e2063341eb2
```

And here's my output on Fedora 13:

```
[user@fedora:~]# python --version
Python 2.6.4
[user@fedora:~]# cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 13 (Goddard)
[user@fedora:~]# python test_hash.py
3d29b0b5ebf500f22b459e1888508d194ffd20707413b69730228e1bd124698f5596a6ef9aadf593b216dba3603e8e2a6871e49a23aadc1b4985bbba92275975
1f0afa06c96447bb15a0389c738e14faa2156bc4a71f03d0300eab6e4386b46cfc7ea3514c6160a2be4213dc1fff80a7aac7e726f01807badd3b3d7edc4f8410
3d29b0b5ebf500f22b459e1888508d194ffd20707413b69730228e1bd124698f5596a6ef9aadf593b216dba3603e8e2a6871e49a23aadc1b4985bbba92275975
3d29b0b5ebf500f22b459e1888508d194ffd20707413b69730228e1bd124698f5596a6ef9aadf593b216dba3603e8e2a6871e49a23aadc1b4985bbba92275975
```

Here's my output on Fedora 16:

```
[user@fedora:~]# python --version
Python 2.7.3
[user@fedora:~]# cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 16 (Verne)
[user@fedora:~]# python test_hash.py
86f43abba8d46fe17cfb6dd1a986b1d086e81a5ad6e3d5c518dc10e8c7229dc366a4129275a609cda7b87cf0afaf82295421098159327e46b7541e2063341eb2
86f43abba8d46fe17cfb6dd1a986b1d086e81a5ad6e3d5c518dc10e8c7229dc366a4129275a609cda7b87cf0afaf82295421098159327e46b7541e2063341eb2
86f43abba8d46fe17cfb6dd1a986b1d086e81a5ad6e3d5c518dc10e8c7229dc366a4129275a609cda7b87cf0afaf82295421098159327e46b7541e2063341eb2
86f43abba8d46fe17cfb6dd1a986b1d086e81a5ad6e3d5c518dc10e8c7229dc366a4129275a609cda7b87cf0afaf82295421098159327e46b7541e2063341eb2
```

Notice the issue seems limited to Fedora 13 or Python 2.6. What would be causing this?

Comment: It should be consistent. Make sure you are hashing exactly the same text. Trailing newlines are often overlooked

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the same. There's nothing for me to overlook. I'm doing get_text_hash(open(fn).read()).

Comment: @gnibbler, I've added example code to reproduce the issue. The issue seems isolated to Fedora 13 or Python 2.6.

Comment: Can you try installing Python 2.6 on any of the other two systems?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you're trying to do with unicode here, why you're using `readlines()` with a binary file, or even whether or not your file will have been flushed when you read it (you open a file and write to it, but you neither close nor flush it before you read from it).  None of your hashes are right, or so it seems to me.

```
~/coding$ sha512sum image.png 
fc704b0cbc532793ba727df9520e8046adf079a80faaffc2d4741ea61a7a506cb79e31ee4338c17d0acf77a9290a969ac63c0e672be09e5c8fc4dcd32c8b62ee  image.png
~/coding$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha512(open("image.png").read()).hexdigest()
'fc704b0cbc532793ba727df9520e8046adf079a80faaffc2d4741ea61a7a506cb79e31ee4338c17d0acf77a9290a969ac63c0e672be09e5c8fc4dcd32c8b62ee'
```

This even works in 2.5.6:

```
Python 2.5.6 (r256:88840, Jul 12 2012, 12:21:58) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux3
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha512(open("image.png").read()).hexdigest()
'fc704b0cbc532793ba727df9520e8046adf079a80faaffc2d4741ea61a7a506cb79e31ee4338c17d0acf77a9290a969ac63c0e672be09e5c8fc4dcd32c8b62ee'
```

If you compare even the first few bytes of `image_content` with what you're actually encoding in (say) `get_text_hash`, you see the difference:

```
>>> image_content[:6]
'\x89PNG\r\n'
```

Now you interpret this as a unicode string and throw away anything you don't understand:

```
>>> unicode(image_content[:6], errors='replace', encoding='utf-8')
u'\ufffdPNG\r\n'
```

And then you encode this again:

```
>>> unicode(image_content[:6], errors='replace', encoding='utf-8').encode('utf-8')
'\xef\xbf\xbdPNG\r\n'
```

It's this last that you're taking the hash of, which is obviously a different bytestring than the original.

To address the particulars of the question (the above was simply too long for a comment): as @gnibbler noted immediately, it's far more likely that the final strings you're asking the hash of vary.  Simply put in a few print statements to compare what the different versions are doing, and you'll find the problem quickly.  (My guess is a different result of the unicode encoding, for what it's worth.)

Comment: Originally, hashlib's .update() was throwing errors based on the encoding of the input text. I'm converting to unicode to normalize the input to something that won't throw encoding errors. The use of readlines() is also a throwback from when I was using it to only hash text files, but you're right, I should simply to .read(bytes) if I want to incrementally read a file.

Comment: @Cerin: the basic point is that you don't take the hash of text strings, you take the hash of bytestrings.  This is more explicit in Python 3, where `hashlib.sha512("somestring")` returns `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`.  And it doesn't make sense to interpret non-Unicode data as Unicode.

Comment: Then could you suggest an approach I should be taking to convert a unicode and non-unicode string into a form I should give to hashlib?